# Which WiFi Module?

Tags: wifi

We've been battling for a while with the MRF24WB0 wireless (802.11 b/g) module by microchip to finish up a project, and we are now realizing that getting it to work with most routers, and using all the various authentication types like WEP/WPA/WPA2 is quite the task.

We have seen other modules available, such as the Roving RN-171 and the Rabbit Semiconductor SPB105-WiF.

I'm wondering if any of you guys has had some experience with Wifi modules for commercial applications, and if yes which solution you would recommend.

Many thanks,
D.

Comment: RN-XV / RN-171 (both same module, different form factor) is rather easy to use, versatile, and has been robust in my experience.

Comment: Could elaborate on the auth difficulties you're having?

Comment: OK, thanks boardbite, I'll investigate this module a bit more.

Comment: Mng: With some routers we have tested it will connect fine using WEP for example, while with others it connects using only open security. Unfortunately I can't elaborate more as I don't know the cause of this..

Comment: You know, Microchip acquired Roving Networks.

Comment: Ok, we did some work with the MRF last night, and I am realizing that perhaps we shouldn't expect it to play with every router. Microchip states that the module has been certified by the 'WiFi Alliance', so it should be compatible with routers with the same certificate. And I believe them. Might be an implementation issue on our side, or a problem with the stack, but not with the module itself..

Comment: Recommendation questions are not a great fit without a lot more detail but it looks like you have found your issue.

Comment: Too bad this got closed.  I could have explained how the Microchip (former ZeroG) module appears not to work with many routers because, having to do with not getting broadcast packets and therefore no ARP requests.

Comment: @OlinLathrop If it was discussing why the module did not work it would stay open, but it seems to have ended just asking for a list of other module solutions. And edit to focus it to a technical discussion and a reopen would be fine by me, and I already would have, but the user already found their issue it seems and it would serve no current purpose.